# remove old rows from HTML-table and insert new rows with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which shows me results when I click on a search button. It works so far, you can see it here:

```js
$('#search').click(function() {
   data=[{"city":"Berlin","cStatus":"G"},{"city":"Hamburg","cStatus":"G"},{"city":"München","cStatus":"P"}];
  
  if(data){
     var len = data.length;
     var txt = "<tbody>";
     if(len > 0){
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
          if(data[i].city && data[i].cStatus){
             txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].city+"</td><td>"+data[i].cStatus+"</td></tr>";
          }
        }
        if(txt != ""){
          txt +="</tbody>"; 
          $("#table").append(txt);
        }
     }
  }     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<button id="search">suchen</button>
```

The Problem is, that it appends the results when I click the search button more then one times. It should first remove the old rows (or the whole tbody). I have tried a lot like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var row = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

function deleteRow () {
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
};
```

but it didnt work in my example. Can sombody make a working example, which schows only three rows even when I click the search-button two times or more often?

Comment: you can use empty() like  $("#table tbody").empty().append(txt);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `append` with `html`.

Check the code [here](http://jsbin.com/dewejivedi/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

Write $("#table tbody").empty(); before append

```js
$('#search').click(function() {
   data=[{"city":"Berlin","cStatus":"G"},{"city":"Hamburg","cStatus":"G"},{"city":"München","cStatus":"P"}];
  
  if(data){
     $("#table tbody").empty(); // Add this line before append. It will clear the previous data and appends new one.
     var len = data.length;
     var txt = "<tbody>";
     if(len > 0){
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
          if(data[i].city && data[i].cStatus){
             txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].city+"</td><td>"+data[i].cStatus+"</td></tr>";
          }
        }
        if(txt != ""){
          txt +="</tbody>"; 
          $("#table").append(txt);
        }
     }
  }     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<button id="search">suchen</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#search').click(function() {
   data=[{"city":"Berlin","cStatus":"G"},{"city":"Hamburg","cStatus":"G"},{"city":"München","cStatus":"P"}];
  
  if(data){
     var len = data.length;
     var txt = "<tbody>";
     if(len > 0){
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
          if(data[i].city && data[i].cStatus){
             txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].city+"</td><td>"+data[i].cStatus+"</td></tr>";
          }
        }
        if(txt != ""){
          txt +="</tbody>"; 
          $("#table").html(txt);
        }
     }
  }     
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<button id="search">suchen</button>
```

Comment: You will use append if you want to keep the previous records. But you use html() if you need to refresh it

Comment: I have given the same answer before you @Franco . Please check other answers before you submit

Comment: @SathvikCheela I am sorry for that but I didn't do it by purpose. As you know while you are editing the post you can not see the incoming answers. This happen very often when you are reading or editing the code.

Comment: I am just informing you.. That's it @Franco

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".....").click(function (e) {
                $("....").find('tr').remove();
                $("....").find('thead').remove();
            });
```

I think you can use this one as well.